# How to make the options in the dropdown selectable using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new to programming. i want to display a list of users when user enters @ character and filter the user list when user types @somestring. i have the filtered list shown in the div. now i want them to be selectable and once user clicks the option then it should concatenate the option selected into the already entered text in input field.

So for example if user enters
hello @ then the dropdown with all users should list and when he selects one of the options say user1 the input now should look like hello user1. how can i do it.

Below is what i have tried so far,

```
class UserMention extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text:'',
            user_mention:false,
        };
        this.user='';
     }
     get_user = s => s.includes('@') && s.substr(s.lastIndexOf('@') 
     + 1).split(' ')[0];

     user_list = [
         {name: 'user1'},
         {name: 'first_user'},
         {name: 'second_user'},
     ];

     handle_input_change = (event) => {
         let is_user_mention;
         if (event.target.value.endsWith('@')) {
             is_user_mention = true;
         } else {
             is_user_mention = false;
         }

         this.setState({
             is_user_mention: is_user_mention,
             [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
         });
         this.user = this.get_user(event.targe.value);
     }  

     render = () => {
         const user_mention_name = get_user(this.state.text);
         return {
             <input
                 required
                 name="text"
                 value={this.state.text}
                 onChange={this.handle_input_change}
                 type="text"/>
              {this.state.is_user_mention &&
                <div
                    className="user_mention_dropdown"
                    style={{

                    }}>
                    {this.user_mention_list
                        .map((o,index) => (
                            <div
                                key={index}
                                style={{
                                    padding: '10px 20px',
                                }}>
                                {o.user_name}</div> ))
                      }
                  </div>}
                 {this.user &&
                     <div>
                         {this.user_list.filter(user => 
                             user.name.indexOf(this.user) 
                             !== -1).map((user,index) => (
                              <div key={index}>{user.name}
                              </div>
                              )) 
                          }
                       </div>
                  }
            );};}
```

Comment: It's not a valid code, there is no such syntax: `this.state = {
            text='',
            user_mention=false,
        };`

Comment: i missed it edited

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found an answer to my question. I have created a component to select the option. 
Code is as below,

```
export default class SelectOptions extends React.PureComponent {
    handle_option_select = (value) => {
        this.props.on_change(value);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.values.map((value, index) =>
                    <Option
                        value={value.user_name}
                        on_select={this.handle_option_select}/>

                    )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export class Option extends React.PureComponent {
    handle_option_select = () => {
        this.props.on_select(this.props.value);
    };

    render = () => {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handle_option_select}>
                {this.props.value}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And in the usermention component use it like below,

```
<Select
    on_change={this.handle_select_value}
    values={values}
 />}
```